# Why is aws charging for kms when calling lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kms

With each lambda invoke either with AWS API or API Gateway HTTP, kms usage is increasing while I haven't added any key management with KMS. Is this indirect cost by aws on lambda usage or there is option to disable kms on lambda invoke.

Comment: are you encrypting your env variables in aws lambda using KMS?

Comment: @AshishModi no I am using environment variables which are unencrypted while it looks AWS charges for KMS even if no customer key are created by default

Answer (score 2):

Each AWS account has a default KMS managed key to encrypt/decrypt the data store and connections.

There should be a section to ask you if you want to encrypt/protect your data when you create Lambda/EC2/DBs, if you click `yes`, then the default key will be used.

That's how you get charged. You can ask their customer service, and they may refund with unnecessary calls.

Comment: I couldn't find any section asking to enable/disable Encryption in Lambda. But I asked AWS support they told me that environment variables in Lambda does this by default which can be disable by AWS Support at the cost of deleting the env data.